# binary search tree unsorted array

Tags: insert, tree, binary-search-tree

I have a problem trying to insert elements on my BST given an unsorted array. The output gives me a segmentation fault, but I can't pinpoint the location of my error. I'm pretty sure that something is wrong with my insert, but I'm not sure what. If anyone can give me insight that would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct BST{
    BST* left;
    BST* right;
    int data;
};

BST* init(int data){
    BST* a = new BST;
    a->data = data;
    a->right = NULL;
    a->left = NULL;
    return a;
}

BST* insert(BST* root, int data){
    if (root == NULL)
        root = new BST;
    else{
        BST* current = root;
        if (current->data >= data)
            insert(current->right, data);
        else
            insert(current->left, data);
    }
    return 0;
}

void inorderTraversal(BST* root)
{
    if(root == NULL) 
        cout << "No node" << endl;
    inorderTraversal(root->left);
    cout << root->data << endl;
    inorderTraversal(root->right);
}


int main(){
    BST* tree = init(5);
    int a[8] = {1, 3, 5, 6, 3, 9, 10, 46};
    cout << "seg fault" << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++)
        insert(tree, a[i]);
    cout << "seg fault here" << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the problem is in your `for` loop. You are looping too far. Try using `a.size()` instead of `sizeof(a)`. With `sizeof(a)` you are requesting the size of the array in bytes, which is probably returning 32.